# Trying start RabbitListener on command after builded Application - RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry is empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I searched all over the stackOverFlow and couldn't find an answer.

I need to start RabbitListener on command - from just REST send request to start this listener (no other option).

So I found that I need set properties in Listener like that: `@RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue", id = "listener_id", autoStartup = "false")` (of course is albo annotation `@Component`).

I made also initializer class using implementation of `ApplicationContextAware` and `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` like below:

```
@Slf4j
 @Component
public class ListenerInitializer implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void startListener() {
        RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry listenerRegistry = applicationContext.getBean(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.class);
        listenerRegistry.getListenerContainer("listener_id").start();
        log.info("Listener started.");
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

And when I tried to use method `startListener()` mostly I received `NullPointerException: null` like `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` doesn't exist. I wrote mostly, because sometimes (every time I make `mvn clean install`) it works and everything is fine. But mostly I received `NullPointerException`.

With `@Autowired` of `ApplicationContext` same situation.

I tried with:
`@Autowired RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry`
but in that case shows me that `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` bean doesn't exist (also through `@RequiedArgsConstructor`.

I tried also to make configuration like below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
class ListenerConfig {

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("listener")
    ListenerInitializer ListenerInitializer() {
        return new ListenerInitializer();
    }

    @Bean(name = "listener")
    Listener listener() {
        return new listener();
    }
}
```

and also doesn't work.

Anybody have any idea how I can fix it? I guess I need to initialize injection of `ApplicationContext` into `ListenerInitializer` as late as possible due to need to initialize itself `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry`, but how to do it?

Many thanks for any advice

edit:
I call it to start through controller

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
class RestController {

       private final ListenerInitializer listenerInitializer;

    @GetMapping("/startListener")
    ResponseEntity<String> startListener() {
        listenerInitializer.startListener();
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Listener started.");
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to understand from where you use that `startListener()`. Might turn out that you call it too early.

Comment: `getBean()` will throw an exception for a missing bean. Are you sure the NPE is on the registry and not on `getListenerContainer()`? If the latter, it is probably too. early, you are accessing the registry before the listener is registered.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I send request through REST Controller. I have there method that call `.startListener()` in `ListenerInitializer`

Comment: @GaryRussell for sure. NPE is in line: `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry listenerRegistry = applicationContext.getBean(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.class);`

Comment: Any chances you can share with us some simple project to reproduce this problem?

Comment: @GaryRussell ok, sorry - you have right  - it throw NPE on `getListenerContainer()`, but I have also few times as I wrote in previous comment. But still - I call it, after I build Application - through REST Controller so it cannot be due to time

Comment: @ArtemBilan unfortunately no, it is a part of big project

Comment: @ArtemBilan Or you meant to create some simple project and copy that classes to imitate same problem? I'm not sure that isn't due to it is big project so it is a lot of beans, but if you meant that just told me so I will try to make something

Comment: Big project... So, perhaps you have many `ApplicationContext` instances where a wrong one is injected into your `ListenerInitializer`, but that `@EnableRabbit` is initialized in the other one. Yeah.. Would be great to see a small project which can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I not sure Big Project as you think - it's just not a simple project. Around 30-40 classes. And for sure anywhere is not pulled out and intentionally used `ApplicationContext` as I tried to do it.

I tried without `@EnableRabbit` in `Configuration` class and also I tried to use `@EnableRabbit` above `ListenerInitializer`, but is the same problem.

Ok, I will try to make some simple project to demonstrate problem (of course if will be)

Comment: @ArtemBilan also is not on this way that implementation of `ApplicationContextAware` inject default `ApplicationContext` into `ListenerInitializer` in field of `ApplicatinContext`? Is not opposite or I don't know something?

Comment: No, that's OK. That's why I'm confused. The `@EnableRabbit` does register that `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` for us in the application context. Therefore it really must be available there...

Comment: @ArtemBilan I tried with `@EnableRabbit` everywhere. On `RabbitMqConfig`, `ExampleApplication` (SpringbootApplication) and above `ListenerInitializer`. Nothing changed, I checked that I don't have anywhere more `@EnableRabbit`. Of course only in one place in same time

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is going to help you somehow, but here is a fully working Spring Boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So75236736Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So75236736Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    Listener listener() {
        return new Listener();
    }

    public static class Listener {

        @RabbitListener(queuesToDeclare = @Queue("myQueue"), id = "listener_id", autoStartup = "false")
        void handle(Object body) {
            System.out.println("Received: " + body);
        }

    }

    @Component
    public static class ListenerInitializer implements ApplicationContextAware {

        private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        public void startListener() {
            RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry listenerRegistry =
                    this.applicationContext.getBean(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.class);
            listenerRegistry.getListenerContainer("listener_id").start();
            System.out.println("Listener started");
        }

        @Override
        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        }

    }

    @RestController
    public static class StartListenerController {

        private final ListenerInitializer listenerInitializer;

        public StartListenerController(ListenerInitializer listenerInitializer) {
            this.listenerInitializer = listenerInitializer;
        }

        @GetMapping("/startListener")
        ResponseEntity<String> startListener() {
            this.listenerInitializer.startListener();
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Listener started.");
        }
    }

}
```

Only difference that I don't use an `@EnableRabbit` explicitly, but rather rely on the auto-configuration. I also don't declare `ListenerInitializer` as a `@Bean` since it is already marked with `@Component` and that is enough for Spring Boot to scan it.

Comment: I had the same like yours and still have a problem.`Listener` not as a `@Bean`, but as `@Component`. I looked deeper and its very weird:
 I have 2 listeners. 1 of them with annotation `@Component` and `@RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue")`. 2 of them `@Component` and `@RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue2", id = "listener_id",  autoStartup = "false"). I changed method `startListener` to also print all of registered listener in `listenerRegistry.getListenerContainers()`. Weird is that that it print first Listener (basic annotation of `@RabbitListener`) and second one no, like is not exist. How?

Comment: I added a second `@RabbitListener` into my `Listener` class and it shows both containers from the `listenerRegistry.getListenerContainers()`. Pehaps your second one is in a class which is not visible for the scan...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution and sorry for bother you guys. Lack of knowledge. Still I don't know how it possible it works before, because I didn't changed anything, cause I was sure it should be like that, but solution was to move annotation `@RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue2", id = "listener_id",  autoStartup = "false")` from over a class to over a method or add `@RabbitHandler` over a method.

Thank you @Artem Bilan for your help!